How to load entire text file as record in AWS Athena
I have a bunch of small text files with multi-line, unstructured data, stored in S3.
Since these files don't have a regular format, I'd like to create an Athena table where every file is parsed as a single record.
Something like:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_db`.`my_table` (
    `data` string
)
<some configuration>
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/my-folder/';

I've tried both the LazySimpleSerDe and the RegexSerDe ways, but without success.
How can achieve this?

I wonder whether you can set the line.delimiter to an unused character so the whole file is interpreted as belonging to one line?

Trying the hint, but no luck. I still obtain a record for every line

try this:
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_db`.`my_table` (
    `data` string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'serialization.format' = '\n'
)
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/my-folder/';


It doesn't work. With this configuration, it creates a record for every line.
